# loop between redux store and database causing dispatch action from reducer

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, synchronize

I have a JavaScript application that uses a redux store to keep track of the application's current state.  I recently added the ability to push the state of the redux store up to an online database being served up by a remote website (Firebase).

What this means is that when the user logs into the application, the state of the redux store is pulled from the database, and applied using an action, so that the state of the application is setup correctly.

Next I added the ability for the application to automatically push changes to the redux store up to the database when something changes.  This part works by itself also.

The problem that I'm running into now is when I enable both at the same time.  I have a requirement where more than one user can be connected to an online database "session".  This means that both users need to listen to changes from the database to synch their own redux stores accordingly.  The problem that I'm seeing is when I try to allow updates from the local redux store to get pushed up to the database.  The browser is complaining about redux dispatching actions from the reducer.  What is happening, is in the application, a user kicks off an action to update the state of the redux store.  In the reducer I see there is a change to the store so I have a call out to the database to update its state.  When the database state changes, I have a listener that fires to notify me that the redux store needs to be updated.  This then kicks off another action to update the redux store and this is where I get the error.  How do I break this loop?

I need the ability to listen for changes in the database and have those changes kick off actions to update the redux store.  But I also need the ability for the redux store to listen to changes and have it kick off updates to the database when the store changes.  I don't want to get into an infinite loop, and I need to be able to handle the case gracefully when 2 users make different changes to their own redux stores and have both of their changes registered in the database.

Comment: Are you listening for changes in the database due to syncing with the app for the same user on another webpage?

Comment: I haven't decided if i should allow or prevent a user from logging into the same database session from multiple browser tabs.  So currently i don't do anything special if a user tries to do this, but i am currently not testing this

Comment: If it was, then you could have some log entry tracking if your redux has the latest changes before it tries to update itself. You need to decide whether the app's redux or database's redux is the single source of truth. Using that decision with a combination of logs will help your app decide what to do next.

Comment: The database has to be the source of truth as it is the only thing that multiple users can access. That being said i still need a local redux store to keep the app working even when users are not logged in and the app is only being used locally

Comment: Then just keep a log of changes. Whenever you upload the latest changes to your db, return and store the timestamp. Whenever the db sends a message back due to db change, include the timestamp of the change and compare against what you previously stored. If its the same, ignore the db's update.